# ggplot Barplot multicategoric problems

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have this issue while using ggplot and creating a bar chart with two axes. I've managed to get the bars as I wanted, but I can't seem to change the axis labels on the x-axis. Every two bars correspond to "Resistant" and "Susceptible." Then, the first 12 bars are for 48 hpi,

```
 
 DF_blood <- data.frame(Group = c("Resistant", "Susceptible"), 
                  Host_DEGs = c(3558, 5635), 
                  Viral_counts = c(0.4771213, 5.608774))
 


 DF_Lung <- data.frame(Group = c("Resistant", "Susceptible"), 
                  Host_DEGs = c(126, 10866), 
                  Viral_counts = c( 1.531479, 6.325484))
 

 
 DF_NasalT_72 <- data.frame(Group = c("Resistant", "Susceptible"), 
                  Host_DEGs = c(2830, 4632), 
                  Viral_counts = c(0, 4.716613))
 
 DF_NasalT_48 <- data.frame(Group = c("Resistant", "Susceptible"), 
                  Host_DEGs = c(81, 6126), 
                  Viral_counts = c(2.41162, 4.985206))
 

 # Combina los dataframes DF de sangre, pulmón y turbinate nasal en uno solo
 combined_df <- rbind(DF_blood, DF_Lung, DF_NasalT_48, DF_NasalT_72)
 
 
 DFlong <-  combined_df |> pivot_longer(cols = -Group, names_to = "Type") |> 
   mutate(scaled_value = ifelse(Type == "Host_DEGs", value, value / 0.001))
 

 DFlong$Sample <- c("Blood", "Blood", "Blood", "Blood", "Lung", "Lung", "Lung", "Lung", "Nasal_Turbinate", "Nasal_Turbinate", "Nasal_Turbinate", "Nasal_Turbinate", "Nasal_Turbinate", "Nasal_Turbinate", "Nasal_Turbinate","Nasal_Turbinate")
 
 DFlong$Timepoint <- c("48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","48hpi","72hpi","72hpi","72hpi","72hpi")
 
 
 
g2 <- ggplot(DFlong, aes(x = interaction(Group, Timepoint, Sample), y = scaled_value, fill = Type)) + 
   geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
   scale_y_continuous(name = "Host DEGs", limits = c(0, 11000), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 0.0009, name = "Viral gene counts (log10)")) +
   labs(y = "Host DEGs") +
   theme_minimal() +
              theme_classic() +
              theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "lines"),
                    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                    axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

I need help to figure out how add the name of the x-axis in different levels.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. E.g. the `combined_df$Sample <- ...` line has the wrong number of values, there is no data.frame called `DF`, and you define `DFlong` twice?

Comment: Keeping in mind the _minimal_ part of [mcve], you can just give us the data frame as it is at the point you're trying to plot it (or just whatever is needed from it), rather than all the steps of creating it.

Comment: Sorry. this is my first question and "I have to familiarize myself with the format